# Why use conjugation in the Schwarz inequality?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I have a simple question about Schwarz inequality. The original inequality in Mr. Rudin's book is as follows: If $a_1...a_n$ and $b_1...b_n$ are complex numbers, then

$$\left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_j \bar b_j\right|^2 \le \sum_{j=1}^n |a_j|^2 \sum_{j=1}^n|b_j|^2\;,$$
where $\bar b_j$ is the conjugate of $b_j$. But I think if we use $b_j$ in replace of $\bar b_j$, the equality is also correct:

$$\left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_j b_j\right|^2 \le \sum_{j=1}^n |a_j|^2 \sum_{j=1}^n|b_j|^2$$

Proof:
Because $\sum|b_j|^2=\sum|\bar b_j|^2$, we get $\left|\sum a_j \bar b_j\right|^2 \le \sum|a_j|^2 \sum|\bar b_j|^2$, where $\bar b_j$ can be any complex number.
So we can write: $\left|\sum a_jb_j\right|^2 \le \sum |a_j|^2 \sum|b_j|^2$ for any $a_j,b_j\in C$

And if this is correct, why do people bother to write $\left|\sum a_j \bar b_j\right|^2$ instead of $\left|\sum a_j b_j\right|^2$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$(a_1,...,a_n)\cdot(b_1,...,b_n)=\sum a_j \bar{b}_j$ is an [inner product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html). $(a_1,...,a_n)\cdot(b_1,...,b_n)=\sum a_j b_j$ isn't. [Cauchy Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) is more generally a statement about inner products: $|\langle a , b\rangle |\leq \|a\|\|b\|$